# When to update mongo db indexes

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

So I am expecting to have around 2000 collections with 10,000-100,000 documents in the near future and I am trying to figure out how to build the indexes. It seems very simple how to do it on a basic level but then when to run the re-indexing is tripping me up. So assume that I have this function and this creates all the indexes I need:

```
def ensure_indexes(self):
    collections = get_collections()
    for coll in collections:
        coll.ensure_index([('time_stamp', pymongo.DESCENDING])
        coll.ensure_index([('raw_value', pymongo.DESCENDING])
        coll.ensure_index([('time_stamp', pymongo.DESCENDING, ('raw_value', pymongo.DESCENDING])
```

There will be a lot of updates to the database during the day and a few people querying it. Should I make a cron job to run the above function during the night while not many people will be inserting new documents in the collections? If people query the database and the collection has been updated but not the index will that query response not include the recently added documents? Or will newly added documents be included in an index?

Comment: why do you need to rebuild the index?

Comment: Apparently because I misunderstood their behavior. I now see that they automatically update the index with each insert.

Comment: FYI, you don't need the first index `('time_stamp', pymongo.DESCENDING])`, as it is a proper subset of your third index: `('time_stamp', pymongo.DESCENDING, ('raw_value', pymongo.DESCENDING])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to rebuild the indexes under normal circumstances, you only need to create the indexes once, read this from [MongoDB FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/#faq-indexes):

> #### Should you run ensureIndex() after every insert?¶
>
> No. You only need to create an index once for a single collection.
>   After initial creation, MongoDB automatically updates the index as
>   data changes.
>
> While running ensureIndex() is usually ok, if an index doesn’t exist
>   because of ongoing administrative work, a call to ensureIndex() may
>   disrupt database availability. Running ensureIndex() can render a
>   replica set inaccessible as the index creation is happening. See Build
>   Indexes on Replica Sets.

In case of corruption and you need to build the indexes again, use `db.collection.reIndex()`, you can read more from [HERE](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/rebuild-indexes/#rebuild-indexes)